# Two Sum II - Input array is sorted

Tags: java

Leetcode #167 is almost same as #1, but why I cannot only add a if condition?

Q: Given an array of integers that is already sorted in ascending order, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number.

The function twoSum should return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target, where index1 must be less than index2.

Note:

Your returned answers (both index1 and index2) are not zero-based.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:
    Input: numbers = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
    Output: [1,2]

```
The sum of 2 and 7 is 9. 
Therefore index1 = 1, index2 = 2.
```

My code:

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[j] == target - numbers[i]) {
                    if(numbers[i] < numbers[j])
                        return new int[] { i, j };
        }
    }
}
 return null;
}
```

}

Why I always return null? where is my mistake? How to fix it?

Comment: array indexes start with `0` zero, not `1` one - check  loops starting value; (just for readability `number[i] + number[j] == target`  would be a more *natural* check since it resembles what is requested)

Comment: I don't know. You should learn to debug your code. Why are you starting your loop at `i=1` instead of `i=0`? Just because the expected output is not zero based doesn't mean the input isn't either.

Comment: Your target is 9 and you are looping the array from index 1, so it starts from 7 and  then try to add the next index values, So your are not getting the desired output.
If you start the looping from 0, then at 0th index the value is 2 and 1st index the value is 7, then you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Because the question says array starts from 1 does not mean array starts from 1 in java.If you want to return i,j as non-zero you should go from 1 to length+1 and then inside the conditions you should check indexes as i-1,j-1 or just start from 0 and return i+1,j+1.

```
class Solution {
  public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length+1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length+1; j++) {
            if (numbers[j-1] == target - numbers[i-1]) {
                if(numbers[i-1] < numbers[j-1])
                    return new int[] { i, j };
            }
        }
    }
     return null;
  }
 }
```

or you can do,

```
    class Solution {
  public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[j] == target - numbers[i]) {
                if(numbers[i] < numbers[j])
                    return new int[] { i+1, j+1 };
            }
        }
    }
     return null;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum-ii-input-array-is-sorted/

[question]: 167. Two Sum II - Input array is sorted

**Using the two-pointer technique:-**

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        if (numbers == null || numbers.length == 0)
            return null;
        int i = 0;
        int j = numbers.length - 1;
        while (i < j) {
            int x = numbers[i] + numbers[j];
            if (x < target) {
                ++i;
            } else if (x > target) {
                j--;
            } else {
                return new int[] { i + 1, j + 1 };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a tag/s to question.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum-ii-input-array-is-sorted/

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and added code comments on why your previous code has errors. Refer to code below for details.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int target = 9;
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 2, 7, 11, 15 };
        int[] result = twoSum(numbers, target);
        if (result != null) {
            System.out
                    .println("The sum of " + numbers[result[0]] + " and " + numbers[result[1]] + " is " + target + ".");
            System.out.println("Therefore index1 = " + (result[0] + 1) + ", index2 = " + (result[1] + 1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Solution found!");
        }
    }

    public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { // array index starts at 0
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[j] + numbers[i] == target) { // add the current numbers
                    // if (numbers[i] < numbers[j]) // not needed
                    return new int[] { i, j };
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Sample input:

```
numbers = [2, 7, 11, 15];
```

Sample output:

```
The sum of 2 and 7 is 9.
Therefore index1 = 1, index2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting first `for-loop` with `i = 0`, what you should do is start it with `i = 1`.

Working code:

```
public class Solution 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] num = {2,7,11,5};
        int n = 13;
        int[] answer = new int[2];
        answer = twoSum(num,n);
        if(answer != null)
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.printf( answer[i] +" ");
    }


    public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) 
            {
                if (numbers[j] == target - numbers[i]) 
                {
                    if(numbers[i] < numbers[j])
                        return new int[] { i+1, j+1};
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have placed an `IF` before `FOR` in `main()` so that if we find no such integers that adds up to give target integer, it'll not throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better solution as it's much faster and covers all test cases as well:

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    int l = 0, r = numbers.length - 1;
    while (numbers[l] + numbers[r] != target) {
        if (numbers[l] + numbers[r] > target) 
            r--;
        else 
            l++;
        if (r == l) return new int[]{};
    }
    return new int[]{l + 1, r + 1};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int start = 0, end = nums.length -1;
    
    while (start < end){
        if (nums[start]+ nums[end]== target)
            return new int []{start+1, end+1};
        
        if (nums[start]+ nums[end]> target){
            end--;}
        else if (nums[start]+ nums[end]< target){
            start++;
        }
    }
    
    return null;    
}
```